# Convert tabular data to XML in node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, parsing, csv

I would like to find a way to convert a series of tabular data stored in a CSV file to XML using node.js or JavaScript in general and I do not know where to start.

The original data files look like this:

```
2009-11-11 13:57:48|NOVAL|FPNxxx1B40000034|1|1|DATA001XE0OP|NOVAL
2009-11-11 13:57:48|NOVAL|FPNxxx1B40000034S|3|2|DATA001XE0OP|NOVAL 
2009-11-11 13:57:48|NOVAL|PCNxxx1B40000812|24|2|DATA001XE0OP|NOVAL
```

The desired output:

```
<SYSTEM>
<PARENT scanned="FPNxxx1B40000034">
    <PARTNO>PNxxx1B4</PARTNO>
    <CLIENT>CLIENT_NAME</CLIENT>
    <SIDE no="1" parentcode="FPNxxx1B40000034">
        <child code="PCNxxx1B40000793" pos="1" side="1" counterindex="1" state="1" />
        <child code="PCNxxx1B40000794" pos="2" side="1" counterindex="2" state="1" />
        <child code="PCNxxx1B40000795" pos="3" side="1" counterindex="3" state="1" />
    </SIDE>
</PARENT>
```

I realise that the example XML shows some extra tags not included in the original data, but converting the main body of the data is what my question is about.

Comment: Parsing CSV data: https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv Producing XML: https://github.com/dylang/node-xml

Comment: @Oleg thank you for your edit...  one think to mention is that the only information I really need is the FPNxxxxx... and the PCNxxxxx... lists the other elements of the xml file are generated by the application, and the list needs to be ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read your csv, parse it and use something like `xmlbuilder` to build xml

```
var obj = {
  person: {
    name: "John",
    '@age': 35,
    address: {
      city: "Istanbul"
    },
    '#list': [
      { phone: { '#text': "555-1234", '@type': 'home' } }, 
      { phone: { '#text': "555-1235", '@type': 'mobile' } }
    ],
    id: function() {
      return 42;
    }
  }
};

var builder = require('xmlbuilder');
var root = builder.create(obj);
```

Comment: How could I read the values in the 3rd column and add it to the XML?

Comment: @reguia use a csv parser like the guy above mentioned.